# Best way to group all your C# classes in 1 class

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the best way to have all your classes in 1 class, and accessing this 1 class can allow you to access all the other classes, so this

```
using Student.Classes.TextFileHandler;
using Student.Scripts.Constants;
using Student.Classes.Common;
using Student.Classes.Enum;
```

would all be in 1 class, lets say the general class, and when I access the general class, I can access all of the other classes

Comment: Why would you do that? Splitting your logic into classes is a way to have a clear separation of concerns...

Comment: That is the worst idea I've ever heard.

Comment: Its becoming to much to be using the using word on every page for each class

Comment: So how would I unit test this, if it's all one class?

Comment: Quite simply, you cannot.

Comment: You should not do this. Do the opposite. Modularity!

Comment: if i can add 1 class, that gets or sets an instance of other classes to the page where i wanna use it, dont you guys think this is much easier

Comment: Read up on namespaces. I think you use the word class when you mean namespace quite a bit in your question.

Comment: Lappies: no, it's not easier, in fact, it complicates things and it simply bad practice.

Comment: Maybe give an example of how you want it to be used. I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: It's like asking President Obama, instead of mayor, to manage all the cities in US.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to and don't take me wrong here. You have to see that classes should not be laid like that. One class per responsability. It is easy for you and for anyone reading/maintaining the code. You can surely use composition but not the way you are trying to do, that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes in classes:

```
 class Student
 {
     class Classes
     {
         class TextFileHandler
         {
             public void MethodInTextFileHandler() {}
             ...
         }
         class Common
         {
             public void MethodInCommon() {}
             ...
         }
         public void MethodInClasses() {}
         ...
     }
     ...
 }
```

But as others mentiont before: you shouldn't to this. This could be very confusing for the readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespaces instead.

```
namespace Student.Classes
{
   class TextFileHandler
   {
      ...
   }
   class Common
   {
      ...
   }
   class Enum
   {
      ...
   }

}
```

You can also have several classes in different files but in the same namespace

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just implement a `Controller` class. In this class you will initialize other classes then provide properties or function to access instance (or even static function/variable) of those classes.